# Extjs :not componentQuery selector returns 0 instead N elements

Tags: javascript, extjs, component-query

I have 6 containers with `cls: tipoDocumento contrato`:

```
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: 'vbox',
                align: 'center',
                hidden: true,
                cls: 'tipoDocumento contrato',
                listeners: {
                    click: {
                        element: 'el',
                        fn: function (e, t) {
                            alert("FIRMAR")
                        }
                    },
                    mouseover: {
                        element: 'el',
                        fn: function (e, t) {
                            this.addCls('rowGridAzul')
                        }
                    },
                    mouseout: {
                        element: 'el', //bind to the underlying el property on the panel
                        fn: function (e, t) {
                            this.removeCls('rowGridAzul')
                        }
                    }
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'image',
                        src: 'img/custom/XL_firmar.png',
                        width: 66,
                        height: 66,
                        cls: 'imagen_elegir_tipo_documento'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'label',
                        layout: 'fit',
                        text: lang.getString('FIRMAR'),
                        width: 66,
                        cls: 'textoElegirTipoDocumento'
                    }
                ]
            },
```

and 5 with only `cls: tipoDocumento`.

When I use the first componentQuery returns the 6 elements with 'contrato' in their class. But when I use the second componentQuery returns 0 items instead the 5 elements who only have the 'cls: tipoDocumento'.

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#listadoTiposDeDocumento')[0].query("container[cls~=contrato]");

Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#listadoTiposDeDocumento')[0].query("container:not[cls~=contrato]");
```

The cls of this items will be dynamic, so this is the only way I see to to this but I'm doing something wrong and I can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing a parentheses. It should be

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#listadoTiposDeDocumento')[0].query("container:not([cls~=contrato])");
```

See [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.ComponentQuery.html)